# Magento 2.x : How to check if use_default is checked for URL key

Tags: magento-2.1, url-key

> ### Summary:
>
> How can I get value of "Use Default" checkboxes like
>   use_default[url_key].
>
> ### Scenario :
>
> I have a website with multiple store views. the URL key is set in
>   Default configurations of product's SEO section. When I switch stores
>   in front-end I get an error on product pages. After an investigation,
>   I found some products have "Use Default" *unchecked* for the URL Key
>   field.  Now I want to write a custom script that will list all those
>   products which have  ***use_default[url_key]*** unchecked. And maybe
>   next update the field to checked state - with the same script.

Answer (score 0):

For now I fixed it by a workaround :

1. used mysql php admin
2. search for *entity_type = "product"* and *store_id = 6*, (which has all the urls.)
3. exported results into csv
4. deleted id column
5. changed store_id column from 6 to 5. (5 is the store having faulty urls)
6. delete all product urls for store 5 from url_rewrite
7. imported the EDITED csv back to url_rewrite table.
   And this is DONE for now.

BUT I NEED SOLUTION TO ABOVE ONE FOR FUTURE REFERENCE.